# Android app keeps throwing Null Pointer Exception when trying to write data over Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am currently working on a project where i'm building an app that uses Bluetooth to send commands to my Arduino Uno and everything is working perfectly except for the actual sending of data.

Whenever I try to send data it throws a Null Pointer Exception and what I know of these exceptions is that they are thrown when something wasn't initialized or cannot be found (Correct me if i'm wrong). So I think the problem is that my connectedThread wasn't properly initialized but I don't know where to do this and what to do.

There is some other code there for speech-to-text so just ignore that.

I would really appreciate any help or advice.

Thank you so much!

My Main_Activity.java:

```
package marggraffd.developer.com.robot;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements          View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

public static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
private static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
private static final String TAG = null;
Toolbar toolbar;
FloatingActionButton fab;
Button forward, reverse, left, right, stop;

private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
TextView speech;
String text;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;


ConnectedThread connectedThread = null;


Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what) {
            case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.bluetooth_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String s = "Successfully Connected";
                connectedThread.write(s);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuff = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuff);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    init();


    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            turnOnBT();
        }

        getPairedDevices();
        startDiscovery();
    }


}

private void startDiscovery() {
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();

}

private void turnOnBT() {
    Intent intent = new Intent((BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

private void getPairedDevices() {
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (devicesArray.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : devicesArray) {
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());

        }
    }

}


private void init() {

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bForward);
    reverse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReverse);
    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLeft);
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRight);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);
    speech = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    pairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices.add(device);
                String s = "";
                for (int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++) {
                    if (device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))) {

                        s = "(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }

                }
                listAdapter.add(device.getName() + " " + s + " " + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {

            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {


            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                if (btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF) {
                    turnOnBT();
                }
            }

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttons();


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bStop:
            connectedThread.write("e");
            break;
        case R.id.fab:
            speech();
            break;

    }
}

private void speech() {
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, getString(R.string.speech_prompt));

    try {
        startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);


    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        speech.setText(result.get(0));

        text = speech.getText().toString();


        if (text == getString(R.string.forward)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Forward", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (text == getString(R.string.reverse)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reverse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (text == getString(R.string.left)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (text == getString(R.string.right)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (text == getString(R.string.stop)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if (btAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    if (listAdapter.getItem(position).contains("(Paired)")) {

        BluetoothDevice selectedDevices = devices.get(position);
        ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(selectedDevices);
        connect.start();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.bluetooth_unpaired), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;


        try {

            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {

        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {

            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {

            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
            }
            return;
        }


        mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
    }


    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {

        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[9600];
        int bytes;

        while (true) {
            try {
                buffer = new byte[9600];

                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}

private void buttons() {


    forward.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    try {
                        connectedThread.write("e");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Forward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    connectedThread.write("e");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    reverse.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    connectedThread.write("d");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reverse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    connectedThread.write("e");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    left.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    connectedThread.write("b");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    connectedThread.write("e");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    right.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    connectedThread.write("c");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    connectedThread.write("e");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

My activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ECEFF1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#009688"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.amdroic.co,/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/controller"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bStop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_stop_black_24dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bLeft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bStop"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bStop"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bRight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bStop"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bStop"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bForward"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/bStop"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_up_black_24dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bReverse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bStop"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Controller"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/controller"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Bluetooth"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:checked="false">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="Monitor"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_black_48dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#009688"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

My logcat:

```
10-01 18:32:00.466 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:      at marggraffd.developer.com.robot.MainActivity$3.onTouch(MainActivity.java:429)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8130)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2422)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2112)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:       at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1622)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2565)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
10-01 18:32:00.486 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
```

Comment: Hi @Dietmar, what is on your MainActivity.java line 429 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for all the help. I have fixed the problem. I just initialized the thread at the end of the run() in the ConnectThread class and now it works perfectly.

This is what had to be fixed if anyone else is faced with the same problem:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {

        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;


        try {

            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {

        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {

            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {

            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
            }
            return;
        }


        mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();

        connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        connectedThread.start();

    }


    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on you `LogCat` error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 18:32:00.481 21197-21197/marggraffd.developer.com.robot W/System.err:      at marggraffd.developer.com.robot.MainActivity$3.onTouch(MainActivity.java:429)
```

The error is at this line:

```
  connectedThread.write("e");
```

the variable `connectedThread` is still having the value of `null`, review your code for a correct initialization of `ConnectedThread` !

```
...
...
...
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    try {
                        connectedThread.write("e"); //*** connectedThread is NULL
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Forward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Elanasys. Sorry to have to ask but could you possibly show me how I would initialize it, if you can?

Answer (score 0):

You define as class field:

```
ConnectedThread connectedThread = null;
```

And then you have a `Handler` that handles A `CONNECT_SUCCESS` and assigns a new `ConnectedThread` to a local variable, **not** the class field:

```
ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
```

What I don't see in your code is where you actually create a `ConnectedThread` and start it, much less where you assign one to your class field, which you are using frequently to `write`stuff.

So, in your `onTouch` method is a `NullPointerException` thrown, because there is no `connectedThread`.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Sascha Kolberg. I have been trying to start the thread in different places but each time I get more errors. Could you possibly show me where I would do this and how if you can?